# Custom command to go to file whose name matches the current word under cursor?

Tags: vimscript

Let's say I'm editing this text in vim:

```
People are helpful.
```

and I am in normal mode, with my cursor currently on the `h` letter of the `helpful` word.

How could I built a custom command that when run would automatically open in the current directory the file `helpful.md` (if such a file does not exists, then nothing would happen or a new empty file would be opened, whatever is the easiest to implement).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `gf`, you can go to the file under the cursor.

Combined with `set suffixesadd+=.md`, you can achieve your desired behavior. (`suffixesadd` asks `gf` and many other friends to try adding any of the suffixes in its list to the file while searching).

Note that you need to have `'path'` correctly set (it's default is helpful for C programmers; tpope's apathy plugin sets it for many other filetypes). For this specific case, you probably just need `:set path+=.`.

`:help gf` also mentions:

```
            If you want to edit the file in a new window use
            |CTRL-W_CTRL-F|.
            If you do want to edit a new file, use: >
                :e <cfile>
<           To make gf always work like that: >
                :map gf :e <cfile><CR>
<           If the name is a hypertext link, that looks like
            "type://machine/path", you need the |netrw| plugin.
            For Unix the '~' character is expanded, like in
            "~user/file".  Environment variables are expanded too
            |expand-env|.
```